# C++11 std::copy inside functions

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a new cross-platform toolbox and would like to be up-to-date with the C++11 extensions. I ran into a problem, where std::copy doesn't behave as I would expect. If anyone has an explanation, I would very much appreciate this.

I completely understand the errors I get and a work-around is to use old-style memcpy, but
if there is a solution, where I can use std::copy, I would appreciate this.

The error I get is:

error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(const float*&)’

and I'am using gcc 4.7.2-5 with C++11 enabled.

There errors I get for the std::copy within the set function

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

class A {
public:
  float data[3];
  void set(const float c[3]) {
    std::copy(std::begin(c),std::end(c), std::begin(data));
  }
};

int main() {
  const float a[3] = {1,2,3};
  float b[] = {4,5,6};
  std::copy(std::begin(a),std::end(a), std::begin(b));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const float c[3]` as a function parameter is longhand for `const float* c` due to C legacy compatibility.

Try `const float (&c)[3]` or `std::array<float,3> const& c` or the like.

I like `template<class T>using Type=T; Type<float[3]> const& c` myself.

Comment: Okay, It makes sense. I did try typedef float f3[3] and the protype void set(const f3), but it was the same error. I am wrapping my library successfully with SWIG to both Python and Ruby, so I would prefer simple types. Thanks for the explanation - I think I will stick to using memcpy.

Comment: @jensmunk you can pass pointers to arrays, references to arrays, and `std::array`s.  You cannot pass arrays.

Answer (score 4):

This function parameter

```
const float c[3]
```

is actually a pointer to `float`, or `const float*`. It is confusing, and is really used to document that the argument should be an array, but any `float*` could be passed to it. Inside the function, `c` is a pointer and that is why `std::begin` doesn't work.

If you want to pass a reference to an array to a function, you need a different syntax:

```
void set(const float (&c)[3]);
```

Alternatively, you can use a user-defined array type, `std::array<float, 3>`.

Note that `std::begin` and `std::end` live in the `<iterator>` header. Also note that you can use the old-school approach:

```
std::copy(c, c + 3, &data[0]);
```

Comment: I tried this also, but the same error. I think legacy compatibility is the reason for the error

Comment: @JensMunk That should definitely work. But you need to `#include <iterator>`.

Comment: I am aware of that, but it doesn't work. First, g++ 4.7.2-5 cannot , parse the void set(const float (c&)[3]) so usually a make a typdef float f3[3] and this works, but after introducing this I get the same template deduction error. I think Yakk's explanation with legacy compatibility is the explanation. The problem with the need for making a typedef is solved in later release of gcc

Comment: The std::array<float,3> works, I know, but the array reference is not welcome by my compiler

Comment: @JensMunk How weird. Unfortunately, the oldest compiler I have accessible is gcc 4.7.3, so I can't check this.

Comment: I am waiting for the next Debian stable - spent far too much on my life working with bleeding edge. Making a typedef and using it directly should not make a difference, but it does. It's weird

Comment: @JensMunk You may have better luck compiling the proper syntax: `void set(const float (&c)[3]);`.

Comment: Thanks :-) So no compiler issues. If I look in some of my older code, I actually use the correct syntax, but I stopped passing arrays by reference because this makes SWIG screw up the code generation.